# summation of column value till the current record

Tags: php, mysql, sum

How to do query and display the records with the sum of student money on every record?

```
 Student ID   Student Name   Student Money 
 ---------    -----------     --------------
   1           John            100
   2           Jenny           200
   3           Ben             100
   4           Andy            200
   5           Lynna           100
```

Above is my table and i would like to retrieve record in this format:

```
 Student ID   Student Name   Student Money     totalCounting 
 ---------    -----------     --------------   ---------
   1           John               100           100
   2           Jenny              200           300
   3           Ben                100           400
   4           Andy               200           600
   5           Lynna              100           700
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Select s.*, (SELECT SUM(s2.`Money`) from students as s2 WHEre s2.`ID` = s.`ID`) as 'totalCounting' from students AS s;
```

Something like this.

Comment: It's not counting the total, its returning just duplicate column of `student money`.

Answer (score -1):

In php I would look to build an extra key in the array built from the query with a foreach loop. My SQL isn't strong enough to build it into the Query, so...

```
$total = 0;
foreach ($queryResults as $key=>$row){
    $total = $total + $row['student_money'];
    $queryResults[$key]['total_money'] = $total;
}
```

Then build the table with the $queryResults with the new column.